# Thumbnail in ImageView from URL mp4

Tags: android, imageview

Here's my code:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    Bitmap thumbnail;
    ImageView imageView;

    public DownloadFilesTask(ImageView iv) {
        super();
        imageView = iv;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( urls[0], MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND );

    }



    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

And I use it like so....

```
new DownloadFilesTask(holder.imageView).execute("http://192.168.0.3/videoone.mp4");
```

Bitmap result is null every time onPostExecute occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: ThumbnailUtils expects a file path not a url. Save it to disk first then pass the local path to ThumbnailUtils.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a URL??? Im dealing with a ListView full of videos and I don't want to have to download each one of them...

Comment: Not that I'm aware of